# A riddle of companions

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> With none, I am short and may be late
>   With one, I am folk, local to a place
>   With two, behold me! Never first
>   With six, and I am made with curd
>   With seven, I’ll keep you off the ground
>   With ten, alone with water all around
>   With eleven, you could say I’m a friendly fish
>   With thirteen, I refer to me, so selfish
>   With sixteen, I want you to be vegan please?
>   With twenty-three, I’m too heavy to fly with ease
>   With twenty-six, I’m six but also seven
>   But wait, there’s more than just the above eleven
>   With certainty I am as yet unknown
>   With a draft, short, I can help stop you groan
>   With ratio, I am made by a guy
>   And with this final line I ask **what am I?**

---

There is a clear and unique answer which you will know when you have found it.

Comment: I haven't posted a riddle in a minute, and this one may be quite difficult, hopefully someone will still be able to solve. Should be a tricky one for you guys though :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you may be

> Eta

With none, I am short and may be late

> Eta is a short Greek letter.
>  ETA stands for Estimate Time of Arrival

With one, I am folk, local to a place

> [**A**eta](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Aeta) = people indigenous to mountainous parts of Luzon.

With two, behold me! Never first

> **B**eta = second letter of the Greek alphabet

With six, and I am made with curd

> **F**eta = a type of cheese.

With seven, I’ll keep you off the ground

> [**G**eta](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geta) =  a wooden clog.

With ten, alone with water all around

> **J**eta = island in the Bissagos Islands

With eleven, you could say I’m a friendly fish

> **K**eta = a type of salmon

With thirteen, I refer to me, so selfish

> **M**eta, this clue is self-referential

With sixteen, I want you to be vegan please?

> [**P**ETA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETA)

With twenty-three, I’m too heavy to fly with ease

> [**W**eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weta) = a flightless cricket

With twenty-six, I’m six but also seven

> **Z**eta = sixth letter of the Greek alphabet, seven in Greek numerals

But wait, there’s more than just the above eleven
With certainty I am as yet unknown

> Eta can be an unknown in maths
>  **Edit:** Should be **Th**eta, a sort of contraction of **the eta** (thanks OP).

With a draft, short, I can help stop you groan

> [**Ac**eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetazolamide) where AC is short for Air Conditioning,

With ratio, I am made by a guy

> Possibly **Pi**eta (by Michaelangelo) where pi is the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter.

Comment: Correct!! Everything right except for the ‘with certainty’ line. I was going for definite article and theta :)

Comment: Thanks @BeastlyGerbil I've edited for clarification.

Comment: A couple of extra things, the beta line - 'behold me!' was a reference to this site, and Keta can also be known as 'chum salmon' (friendly fish). Well done on solving! Out of interest did you find this hard/easy etc and what gave you the answer?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks, will add later. I actually thought this was quite tricky. Most of the words I didn't know (had to look up). It was linking the PETA and feta that gave it to me in the end, just luck with these things sometimes.