# What am I with zero?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

- With zero I am falling.
- With two I am smart.
- With four I am wet.
- With seven I am food.
- With twenty I am fast.

What am I with zero?

Comment: You're falling!

Comment: @Alex dare you to make it an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are

> **RAIN**!!

And the gimmick is

> to add the letter of the alphabet for the number on the front (e.g. 'with one' would mean add 'a' at the start). I only got this as [I've done this before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97055/a-riddle-of-companions) :P

---

With zero I am falling.

> On your own, you are '**rain**', which falls

With two I am smart.

> With *b* you are a '**brain**', which is smart

With four I am wet.

> With *d* you are a '**drain**', which is wet

With seven I am food.

> With *g* you are '**grain**', which is food

With twenty I am fast.

> With *t* you are a '**train**', which is fast

---

So with zero (a.k.a with nothing added) you are

> **RAIN**