# I am not falling, what am I with zero?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

[I am not falling!!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101790/what-am-i-with-zero)

- With zero I listen.
- With two I growl.
- With four I am close.
- With seven I spin.
- With twenty I flow.

What am I with zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are an

> **EAR**!!

---

With zero I listen.

> An '**ear**' listens

With two I growl.

> A '**bear**' growls

With four I am close.

> A '**dear**' person is close to you

With seven I spin.

> A '**gear**' spins

With twenty I flow.

> A '**tear**' flows

---

And also, per the title

> An ear does not fall, and would be a bit worrying if it did!

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Ear?

> Bear  Dear  Gear  Tear

Comment: Wow beat you to it be 10 seconds, very close :)

Comment: Story of my life :)

Comment: Correct but please add spoiler tags! Replace `>` with `>!`

Comment: Not sure how to do it

Comment: You have 24k reputation how can that be

Comment: Btw I gave you an upvote

Comment: @Alex Orme. This Reveal Spoiler thing is new. I only knew Blockquotes. I am not smart when it comes to these things I guess.