# With zero I propel

Tags: riddle, wordplay

With zero I propel
With two I can be wild
With eight I show age
With eighteen I'm quite loud
With nineteen I'm in a cloud

Not sure how long these have been around, but inspired by:
[I am not falling, what am I with zero?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101812/i-am-not-falling-what-am-i-with-zero)
[What am I with zero?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101790/what-am-i-with-zero)

Comment: would be more fun and challenging if you were to change the location of placing those letters. One can start with placing them at the end? Just an idle thought

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, that one just kind of "popped into mind" after reading the others so idk how many I'll make, but if I do come up with some more... Think it would be necessary to note where the letters are, or at least keep them consistent, or could they be added to beginning, middle, or end of the word as long as base letter were used?

Comment: You can say --with 2 at the end I am -----   and so on. A mediocre example is Car. Carb, card, Carl, Carp, cart etc

Comment: If they are all at the end, I don't think you need to specify they are at the end! These puzzles are relatively easy if everyone knows what these "with <number>" mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Oar

With zero I propel

> Oar (propels a boat)

With two I can be wild

> **B**oar

With eight I show age

> **H**oar (meaning grey or grey-haired with age)

With eighteen I'm quite loud

> **R**oar

With nineteen I'm in a cloud

> **S**oar

Comment: You guys are quick!

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Oar

> Boar, Hoar, Roar and Soar

Comment: I see you learned the spoiler tags! Looks like hexomino beat you by a minute this time though

Comment: I need to learn typing fast!!  :)