# A Riddle of Ages

Tags: riddle, wordplay

At birth, I was everything
At two, I was playful
At three, I wanted to communicate
At six, I experienced a setback
At seven, I was overly bold
At eight, I provided safe passage
By thirteen, I was languishing, abandoned in the suburban wilderness
By twenty, I was a giant
By twenty-three, no one wanted to pay for me any more

Throughout life, this was my inspiration:

> [A riddle of companions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97055/a-riddle-of-companions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are

> All

The idea here is

> To add a letter at the beginning of *me* corresponding to its position in the alphabet as mentioned in each line.

At birth, I was everything

> "At birth" just refers to the word itself, *all*.

At two, I was playful

> **B**all

At three, I wanted to communicate

> **C**all

At six, I experienced a setback

> **F**all

At seven, I was overly bold

> **G**all (bold and impudent behaviour)

At eight, I provided safe passage

> **H**all

By thirteen, I was languishing, abandoned in the suburban wilderness

> **M**all (large enclosed shopping area)

By twenty, I was a giant

> **T**all

By twenty-three, no one wanted to pay for me any more

> **W**all (referencing the US-Mexico border wall that nobody wants to pay for).